# uploading images to nodejs with multer from form

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, multer

Im trying to upload images from an `angular` frontend to a `nodejs` backend using `multer` package

My route:

```
router.post('/fileupload', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res, next) => {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any

 // Did the route activate ?
 res.json({ gotIt : true});

})
```

My HTML form in the angular 2 comp.

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/users/fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But nothing happens on submit - if i test it with `postman` it works. What am i doing wrong here ?

I also tried with just /users/fileupload in the `form action`.

Comment: could you please add the multer code for upload object,
and show me the result of req and res in rout.post

Comment: why is the backend path `/fileupload`, but the form path `/users/fileupload`?

Comment: const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'public/images' })

Comment: route is like that because of i set it in express app.use('/users', userRoute);